# Multiple scrollbars in Review window

Tags: discussion

Didn't notice this until recently so I am guessing it must not have been ever-present. But it's clearly something that needs to be resolved. I am going to tag it as a point of discussion because I am not sure if this was intentional or a bug.

[image]

Comment: I believe this is a bug, though just for confirmation: this is on 100% zoom, right?

Comment: @AndrewT. - Yes. It is at 100% zoom

Comment: Apparently, [it also happened on English.SE](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11676/94616)